# Windows powershell : change default working directory

Tags: powershell

Every time I open a Windows powerShell I need to cd to a particular folder.

Is there a way to configure it in the powerShell parameters (I am thinking of the parameters Json for instance)?

I have found that set-location can be usefull. I tryed "Set-Location": "c:/", in the parameters json but it seems not to work.

Any ideas?

update after thom schumacher's comment:
I think I have already a profil and I am interested in the first one : (a part of my parameteres json)

```
 "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
        },
        "list":
        [
            {
                "guid": "{07b52e3e-de2c-5db4-bd2d-ba144ed6c273}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Ubuntu-20.04",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
                "startingDirectory":"//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/vmelin",
                "colorScheme": "Solarized Dark",
                "fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL"
            },
...
```

adding "Set-Location": "/home/aalidra" in this profil didn't make it.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article about Powershell Profiles.. if you add a profile then you can add the CD that you want:
[PowerShell Profiles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/#:%7E:text=Six%2C%20count%20%E2%80%98em%2C%20six%20different%20PowerShell%20profiles%20,%20%20%24PsHomeProfile.ps1%20%202%20more%20rows%20)

Comment: This is the _best_ way to do this. One could also modify the shortcut so that the 'start in' is set to the folder in question.

Comment: Thx Thom for your answer. I have updated my question accorfing to your suggestion